# Как работать с ToDictionary

Tags: c#

Есть такой вот код

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> dic = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>();
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> o = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string, int>(dic);
Dictionary<string, int> l1 = o.ToDictionary<string, int>(S => dic[S.Key]);
```

Здесь вначале создается обычный словарь, далее он перегоняется в словарь только для чтения. А потом из "только для чтения" вызывается метод `ToDictionary`. Однако ничего не работает уже на этапе компиляции. Почему ? Какую бы реализацию делегата `Func` я не загнал, компилятору все не нравится. При этом еще и возникает такая вот путаница - `Func` имеет такое определение `Func<string, int>`, и при установке в лямбде `S=>...` S - почему-то имеет тип стринг, но далее `S=>S.Key` - то есть он уже оказывается не стринг а KeyValuePair. С чем это может быть связано и как это решить ? Код мой, в учебных целях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените последнюю строку на

```
var l1 = o.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

либо на

```
var l1 = o.ToDictionary(p => p.Key);
```

и все заработает

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо! А из-за чего это ?

Comment: очевидно, что из-за того, что вы подсовывали неправильную лямбду